# Is there a way to replace the texts in the textInput without clicking and using tabs?

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard, shinydashboard

Good day all,

I have created a dashboard for the scanning station whereby the operator is able to observe the details of the item after he or she scanned it with a barcode scanner. The issue I am currently facing is that I am unable to scan the barcode of the item without clicking on the textbox. Ideally, what I want to do is:

1. To allow the operator to scan the barcode straight away on the textbox without clicking on the textbox.
2. Automatically highlight the barcode number in the textbox so the next barcode number can be scanned and the details of the second item can be rendered.

Reproducible example:

- ui.R

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyBarcode)
library(shinyjs)

dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Barcode System"),
    dashboardSidebar(collapsed = T),
    dashboardBody(
 
        useShinyjs(),
        box(width = 4, height = 880,
            shinyBarcode::includeJsBarcode(cdn = TRUE),
                textInput("barcode_no", h3("Scan Barcode No")),
                shinyBarcode::barcodeOutput("scanned_barcode")
        )))
```

- server.R

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyBarcode)
library(shinyjs)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
# Rendering barcode
    output$scanned_barcode<- shinyBarcode::renderBarcode(
        paste("0",input$barcode_no, sep="") # Need to add "0" to all barcode at the front
    )
})
```

#### Note: Here is how to install shinyBarcode

```r
# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("CannaData/shinyBarcode")
```

If you are still unable to install, download the [ZIP file](https://github.com/carlganz/shinyBarcode/archive/master.zip) from [Github](https://github.com/carlganz/shinyBarcode).

Next, openup the zip file and install using the following command:

```r
devtools::install("C:\\Users\\dave\\Downloads\\shinyBarcode-master") # Edit to your download directory
```

#### Preview

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find a solution:

Added this into my UI:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyBarcode)
library(shinyjs)

dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Barcode System"),
    dashboardSidebar(collapsed = T),
    dashboardBody(
            # Added JS script
             tags$head(tags$script("Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('selectText', function(message) {
        $('#barcode_no').select();
      });")),
        useShinyjs(),
        box(width = 4, height = 880,
            shinyBarcode::includeJsBarcode(cdn = TRUE),
                textInput("barcode_no", h3("Scan Barcode No")),
                shinyBarcode::barcodeOutput("scanned_barcode")
        )))
```

Added this into the server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyBarcode)
library(shinyjs)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
# Rendering barcode
    output$scanned_barcode<- shinyBarcode::renderBarcode(
        paste("0",input$barcode_no, sep="") # Need to add "0" to all barcode at the front
    )

observeEvent(input$barcode_no,{
        session$sendCustomMessage("selectText", "select")
    })
})
```

This has resolved 2 issues:

1. Upon starting up the app, the only way for us to key in the barcode number is by clicking or using Tab.
2. After the material number is added, the user will need to click or use tab in order to highlight the previous barcode number and replace it with the second barcode number.